# Freeform user account creation form: handling prior user account exists

Tags: users, plugin-freeform, freeform

This is more or less a duplicate of a support ticket raised with Solspace. I’ve no doubt they will provide an answer but if anyone else has one feel free to pitch in.

---

I'm using [Freeform](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/) forms to register user accounts into a specific user group per form. It could arise that a would-be user is already registered, so I need to handle them trying to create a user account for an email address already in the system.

It appears that `form.hasErrors` prevents a duplicate account being created but doesn’t return any message that that’s what has happened within the `form.errors` loop.

I'm imagining I *could* do something like the following to *assume* that a prior user account is the issue, but it would be good if there was something more systematically robust:

```
{% if form.hasErrors %}
    {% if form.errors|length %}
        {# Report errors #}
    {% else %}
        {# Assume that an existing user account is the issue #}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Is there a better way?